# linq query for getting largest time interval

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I've been getting into some basic linq stuff, but I'm not really sure how to implement this one.

consider a simple object like this

```
public class Movement
{
    int areaId;
    DateTime startTime;
    DateTime endTime;
}
```

this represents a movement of some item. startTime is the time it entered area with areaId. endTime is the time it left that area.
I have a list of these for one item in no particular order. There can be many different movements for any areaId, and none of the times overlap.

```
List<Movement> items = getSomeMovements();
```

I am given a time interval, defined by a low time and a high time. low time is less than high time.

```
DateTime lowTime;
DateTime highTime;
```

I want to get the areaId where the item spent the most time during this time interval.
I'm thinking group by the area, find the total time in each, and select the largest total. Not sure how to do this with Linq though. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it, if I understand your question correctly:

```
var areaTime = from mov in items
               where mov.startTime >= lowTime && mov.endTime <= highTime
               group mov by mov.areaId into grp
               select new
               {
                   AreaID = grp.Key,
                   TimeSpent = grp.Sum(m => (m.endTime - m.startTime).TotalSeconds),
               };

var areaSpentMostTimeIn = areaTime
    .OrderByDescending(at => at.TimeSpent)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with pure LINQ, but more neatly, first declare two functions:

```
TimeSpan Intersection(DateTime start, DateTime end, Movement movement)
{
    DateTime t1 = start > movement.StartTime ? start : movement.StartTime;
    DateTime t2 = end < movement.EndTime ? end  : movemnt.EndTime;
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 - t1 : TimeSpan.Empty;
}
```

then use: `items.OrderByDescending(m => Intersection(lowTime, hightTime, m).FirstOrDefault()`

this will be much cleaner if you add Intersection to the class movement

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
List<Movement> items = getSomeMovements();
Movement result = items.OrderByDescending(m => m.endTime - m.startTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: nope, because there may be many movements per area, so I need to sum up the total time in each area and get the one with the largest total time

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot simpler with Aggregate.  Fully working example with test data:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var movements = new []
{
    new Movement { areaId = 1, startTime = now.AddDays(-10), endTime = now.AddDays(-9) },
    new Movement { areaId = 2, startTime = now.AddDays(-8), endTime = now.AddDays(-7) },
    new Movement { areaId = 3, startTime = now.AddDays(-5), endTime = now.AddDays(-2) },
    new Movement { areaId = 4, startTime = now.AddDays(-2), endTime = now.AddDays(0) }
};

var longest = movements.Aggregate((m1, m2) =>
    m1.endTime.Subtract(m1.startTime) > m2.endTime.Subtract(m2.startTime) ? m1 : m2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Alireza's Intersection function, but then aggregate rather than ordering will be more efficient.